# WPF Datagrid: based on checkbox condition disable another cell in a row for all the rows

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have developed a Custom datagrid with `AutoGenerateColumns = false`,in the code behind i am creating the columns based on the type i need. I have used

`DataGridTemplateColumn` for `string` types ( having cellTemplate and CellEditing Template) and for checkbox type, i have used `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`.

Now the requirement i have is, in the datagrid if user had checked more than 2 check boxes (i.e every row will have only one check box and each row check box click is one count), then a specific column with the name "DisplayName" which is of type Text box should be disabled for all the rows.

i have created a property to maintain the count of the checkBoxClicked and its been properly updated based on checking or un-checking of the chekboxes, now iwant to use this property and disable all the rows where the check box is not checked and only for the Column Name "DisplayName".

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Edited:

I have tried below thing in the code , but its not working. Created a Style for `DataGridCell`. And added a converter, which checks for the column Name i am trying to disable, below is the sample code

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=DataGridUserControl, Path=MaxAddToLabelReached}" Value="true">
         <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource ValueToBrushConverter}}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

And my Converter has logic

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
 {

   try
   {
     DataGridCell dgc = (DataGridCell)value;

     if (dgc.Column.Header.ToString().Equals("Display Name"))
       return false;

   }
   catch (InvalidCastException )
   {
     return Boolean.FalseString;
   }


   return Boolean.TrueString;
 }
```

Requirement:

My requirement is - if i have ten rows , then each and every row will have one checkbox type column by name AddtoLabel, in the same row there wil be one more column by name "Display name", when user checks the checkbox, then the count of checkbox will be one, if the count of the checkbox exceeds two, then my property "MaxAddToLabelReached" will be set to true.Means i should not allow user to check the checkboxs in other rows which are un-Checked. I have created a style to disable all the other checkboxes which are not checked, so the "Addtolabel" column checkboxes which are not checked will be disabled,

this is working fine. In the same way in each row when "MaxAddToLabelReached" then in the "Displayname" column, i have to check the rows whose checkboxes are not checked, and if they are not checked, disable the "DisplayName" column cell for that specific row.

Edited:

The way i have created my Columns for the datagrid is

I have a template created in the XAML as below

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CellTempalte" x:Key="DataGridTemplateColumn">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="DataGridCellTemplateColumn">
      <TextBlock  x:Name="textBlock" DataContextChanged="Cell_DataContextChanged" Margin="0, 0"  Loaded="Cell_Loaded" VerticalAlignment="Top"  
                  >

      </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>              
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="DataGridCellEditTemplateColumn">
                <TextBox   x:Name="celltext"  DataContextChanged="T_Cell_DataContextChanged" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" MinHeight="20" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MouseEnter="datagrid_CellTextBoxEnter" 
                           MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBox_MouseLeftButtonDown_1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In the code behind in Initialize Columns, i create the columns as below

```
       if (columnType == "Text")
        {

           DataGridTemplateColumn dataGridTemplateColumnForText = this.FindResource("DataGridTemplateColumn") as        DataGridTemplateColumn;
           DataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTemplateColumn()
           {
              Header = columnHeadersInfo.colHeaderConfigInfoColl[i].nlsColumnName,
              CanUserSort = true,
              SortMemberPath = columnName,
              ClipboardContentBinding = binding,
              CellTemplate = dataGridTemplateColumnForText.CellTemplate,
              CellEditingTemplate = dataGridTemplateColumnForText.CellEditingTemplate,
              Width = gridColWidth,
              IsReadOnly = isReadOnly,
              Visibility = columnHeadersInfo.colHeaderConfigInfoColl[i].columnVisibility ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden

           });


        }
 else if(columnType == "checkBox")
  {
     var CheckboxCol = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn
      {
          Header = columnHeader,
          Width = gridColWidth,
          IsReadOnly = isReadOnly,
          Binding = binding,
          ClipboardContentBinding = binding,
          CanUserSort = true,
          SortMemberPath = columnHeader,
          ElementStyle = this.Resources["CheckBoxStyle"] as Style,
          EditingElementStyle = this.Resources["CheckBoxEditingStyle"] as Style
      };

      this.DataGrid.Columns.Add(CheckboxCol);

}
```

So with this type of column creation, i am not sure, how i can use the sample code suggested by you.

Comment: Your requirement is unclear. Try to explain the checking of CheckBox more clearly.

Comment: Anjum, I have edited my question and added the requriement

Comment: Please see the answer and tell if this works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Grid to enforce disabled behavior. If `MaxAddToLabelReached` property is false, column will be disabled and vice-versa.

Make sure , you either use a converter, or make `MaxAddToLabelReached` property behave w.r.t code below.

In one of my code, this approach works without problems.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DisplayName" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid IsEnabled="{Binding MaxAddToLabelReached}">
                <TextBox x:Name="DisplayName" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

To disable column based on CheckBox checked state :

XAML :

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
             </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Code :

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /* apply your own condition here */

            Dgrd.Columns[0].IsReadOnly = true; // disable the entire column of all rows

            // to disable only the corresponding cell of the desired column
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)Dgrd.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(chk.DataContext);
            DataGridCell p = (DataGridCell) ((TextBlock)Dgrd.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row)).Parent;
            p.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /* apply your own condition here */

            // exact opposite of Checked event handler

            Dgrd.Columns[0].IsReadOnly = false; 

            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)Dgrd.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(chk.DataContext);
            DataGridCell p = (DataGridCell)((TextBlock)Dgrd.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row)).Parent;
            p.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Anjum, thanks for your reply, as i have set Autogenerate columns to false, and loading columns externally, will it be possible to create a style to trigger only for "Displayname" column and use the logic suggested by you?

Comment: Binding will work surely. Plz try and update me,  I will look into it, I am online now. And why you want to use Trigger ? See my code, I didnt use any Trigger.

Comment: Anjum, Thanks I have updated my question by adding the approach i have taken to create the columns, can you check it.

Comment: In your TemplateColumn code, you are using CellTemplate from a textfile/style. So it should ok.

Comment: @user3326631 It should be easy to add the needed XAML in your cell template.

Comment: Anjum, Sorry i couldnt follow that, i am not sure where to place the code in the XAML mentioned by you, if i place it under datagrid element, it is crashing my datagrid, any suggestions where i can use it, as i am dynamically creating columns, my "display name" column will be created in code-behind and i am trying to add it again in XAML?

Comment: As my cellTemplate is used commonly for all the columns of Text type, i am not sure how i can add specifically for "Display name" Column inside my celltemplate.

Comment: @user3326631 create two such style/templates/txt-files, and load each accordingly based on column name.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, to night i will try what you have suggested by using different templates and will come back to you for any queries. Thanks for the support

Comment: @user3326631 welcome, i dont think , u will have problems with this.

Comment: I have created the datatemplate suggested by you and it works for disabling the displayname column, but one of my requirement was i should disable the "Display Name" column only if the "Add to Label" check box is not checked in that Row and if MaxAddToLabelReached. But in this case it is disabling all the rows with out checking the checkbox checked state. i am trying to find a solution for this, any suggestions from you please

Comment: @user3326631 Create a new property using all the conditions.

Comment: the new property which i created should be set for every row, i.e MaxAddToLabelReached is a common property for the entire gird, but where the checkbox is checked or unchecked is property for checkbox and it varies from row to row, will it be possible to use a converter where the converter gets the converterparameter as the dataGridRow where we can check the value of the checkbox checked state and then disable the text box?

Comment: Any suggestions Anjum?

Comment: @user3326631 Sorry, got buisy with other questions, and forgot urs. Let me do it now.

Comment: sorry for late reply, the suggestions provided by you helped me to fix the problem i was working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use converter class to achieve this. 
Use converter and bind the count property and if the count is greater than 2 then using converter, You can return the bool and then you can achieve the enabling and disabling operation on the grid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply dhruv

Comment: I have tried this, but still not working, i have edited my question, can you please let me know where i am doing wrong

Comment: @user3326631 - your converter should return a boolean not a string. Just return `true` or `false`.

Comment: Chris and Dhruv, if i have ten rows, i should disable only the cells in a row where checkbox is not checked, i.e if maxaddtolabelcount exceeds 2, then in the rows where checkbox is not checked, in that row displayName column should be disabled, in other rows where it is checked it should be enabled.

Comment: @DhruvPanchal  , Dhru did you get a chance to look in to the code ?

Comment: @user3326631 I will update you as soon as possible today